# Excel Lookup between multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need your assistance with Excel. I have the following columns on my worksheet

EmployeeNumber, EmployeeName, SalesID,Email, EmployeeNumberID.

The EmployeeNumber and EmployeeNumberID columns are the key columns as these contain the employee number. The problem is that EmployeeNumber contains all employees from different departments and EmployeeNumberID contains employee from the Sales department.

Could you please assist with highlighting the EmployeeNumber that are not in the EmployeeNumberID column, if we could highlight the entire row that would be great.

Mnay Thanks

Comment: apologies for the late reply. Thank very much for your responses, it really help me address the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is layed out as per the image below, select the range from A2 to E9 and ensure that the upper left cell A2 is your active cell.  Notice in the image the active cell has a light background compared to the grey background of the rest of the selected range.

[image: Layout]

Then go to your HOME ribbon and select conditional formatting.

[image: Conditional Formating]

From the drop down menu that appears select New Rule.

In the New Formatting Rule window that appears select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" at the bottom of the list.  Then click to format button and chose whatever formatting you want to have applied.  I would recommend the Fill tab and then select a colour.

[image: New Formatting Rule]

Enter the following logical check in the "Format values where this formula is true:" box:

```
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$9,$A2)=0
```

It will count the number of times Employee number in column A occurs in Column E.  It will then check to see if that count is zero meaning its not in column or not part of the sales team, and apply the formatting you selected early to all cells in the row from A to E.  **If you only want to colour cells in column A then select A2:A9 as your initial selection area for applying conditional formatting to.  The equation should not need to change.**

### Proof of Concept

[image: PoC]

Comment: The same methodology would apply to using @AlexisOlsen 's formula if your prefer that one.

Answer (score 1):

You just need some conditional formatting. Select the area you want to apply the highlighting to, lets say A:E, then use conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=ISNA(MATCH($A1,$E:$E,0))
```

assuming EmployeeNumber is in column A and EmployeeNumberID is in column E.

What this does is tries to match the EmployeeNumber to a value in column E. If it fails, then it will return `#N/A` and `ISNA` will return `TRUE` and the row will be highlighted.

Note that $A1 should be the top left cell in the range you are formatting. If you start lower, adjust the cell accordingly.